# Phusion Passenger: 'Initialize language runtime' and 'Load or execute application' error with nodejs app

Tags: node.js, passenger, phusion

My nodejs app works fine on my local machine in the dev environment, however getting it to work on the production server is a nightmare.

In a nutshell the app is starting but the content is not loading on the site. It is failing to fully initialize as the screenshot shows.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRrXg.jpg)

Anyone have any ideas about this? Even the hosting company isn't sure what is causing it and I can't find anything relevant on google so far. All I know is it is coming from Phusion Passenger...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my solution in case anyone else runs into this issue.

If you have created a nodejs app using express and have used the express generator to set the app up, you will notice the start up file is called `www` inside the bin folder in your projects directory. Usually it is named `app.js`.

Phusion Passenger looks for `app.js` to start the app. You need to tell Phusion Passenger to look for `./bin/www` inside your config file. It will likely be different for different systems. In apache it is located here:

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_DOMAIN/YOUR_APPNAME.conf
```

You need to add this startup file line:

```
PassengerStartupFile ./bin/www
```

Your config file should look something like this:

```
<Location "/">
    <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
        PassengerAppEnv "development"
        PassengerEnabled on
        PassengerBaseURI "/"
        PassengerAppRoot "/home/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_DOMAIN"
        PassengerAppGroupName "YOUR_APP_NAME"
        PassengerRuby /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/libexec/passenger-ruby27
        PassengerPython /usr/bin/python
        PassengerNodejs /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node
        PassengerAppType node

        PassengerStartupFile ./bin/www
        
    </IfModule>
</Location>
```

Then you just need to save the file, rebuild the apache http config file and restart apache.

I used the terminal inside WHM to run these two lines:

1# `/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf`

2# `/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_httpd`

Combined # `/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf && /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_httpd`

The instructions in this post are found here:

https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/